# Powershell: Delete Every n Files

Tags: loops, powershell, delete-file

I just imported a bunch of pictures, and realized that there's 3 copies of each pictures, but they're named sequentially.

Basically these three files are the same:

```
P5240901.dng
P5240902.dng
P5240903.dng
```

And that, for about 1600 pictures.

I was looking into writing a simple PowerShell script (I use Windows) that would look into the directory of these files, and keep 1 file out of three, just looping through a range of files.
I didn't find something that would deal with the 'P' character before my file, and I'm not familiar with PowerShell language.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything in the dir follows the naming convention & is in a set of 3 something like this should work:

```
$mydir = 'C:\path\to\files'
[int]$idx = 1
get-childitem $mydir|sort-object {$_.Name} |foreach-object{
    if ($idx % 3 -ne 1){ #get the modulus
        $_ |remove-item
    }
    $idx++
}
```

Comment: How can I modify this to start erasing at a certain filename? For example, I have lots of other pictures in my folder that don't have that problem, so I only want to erase from P5240901.dng to P5240999.dng.

Comment: you could use a match like so: 'get-childitem $mydir|where-object {$_.Name -match "P52409*"}|sort-object {$_.Name} |foreach-object{', or alternatively split the name string at a certain point and cast it as an integer to see whether it's within a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which will keep only the 1st file in each group of files whose names are the same except for the last character before the filename extension, assuming that character is a digit (syntax assumes PSv3+):

```
'P5240901.dng', 'P5240902.dng', 'P5240903.dng', 'A1.dng', 'A2.dng', 'singleton.dng' | 
  Group-Object { $_ -replace '^(.+)\d\.', '$1' } | 
   ? Count -gt 1 |
     % { $_.Group[1..$($_.Group.Count)] }
```

yields:

```
P5240902.dng
P5240903.dng
A2.dng
```

Replace the sample input array with a call to `Get-ChildItem -File`, and prepend  `Remove-Item` to `$_.Group[1..$($_.Group.Count)]` to perform actual deletion.

<sup>The above command uses a *string* array with input *filenames*, but the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` will effectively act the same in a string context: they will expand to their respective filenames.</sup>

The advantage of this solution is that it doesn't rely on input files appearing strictly in groups of 3:

- Any group of input files sharing the same name except for a digit before the filename extension that has at least 2 members (and any number beyond that) will have every member but the 1st deleted.
- Any other files are left untouched.

**Explanation:**

- `Group-Object { $_ -replace '^(.+)\d\.', '$1' }`

  - effectively groups the input files by the portion of the filename they share (but only if they share everything but the last char. before the filename extension, and if that char. is a digit).
- `? Count -gt 1`

  - only passes on those resulting groups that have at least 2 members.
- `% { $_.Group[1..$($_.Group.Count)] }`

  - processes each group's files, except the 1st.

---

**Update:** Here's a variation prompted by the OP's later comments: 
The following, given input filenames such as `P5240901.dng, P5240902.dng, ..., P5240910.dng, P5240911.dng, ..., P5240990.dng, P5240991.dng, ..., P5240999.dng`, will consider each group of *10* files a group (based on the tens place), and within each group only retain the 1st file:

```
1..99 | % { "P52409$('{0:00}' -f $_).dng" } | 
  Group-Object { $_ -replace '^(.+\d)\d\.', '$1' }   | 
   ? Count -gt 1 |
     % { $_.Group[1..$($_.Group.Count)]}
```

yields:

```
# tens place of 0; skips ...01.dng
P5240902.dng
P5240903.dng
... # up to ...09.dng
# tens place of 1; skips ...10.dng
P5240911.dng
P5240912.dng
... # skips ...20.dng, ...30.dng, ...
# tens place of 9; skips ...90.dng
P5240991.dng
P5240992.dng
...
P5240999.dng
```

In order to only pass the files of interest to the command, replace the sample input array with
`Get-ChildItem P52515[0-9][0-9].dng`.

Comment: If I run this code on a test folder with photos P5251500.dng to P5251520.dng, it yields: ...00, ...10 and ...20. How do I control it so that it erases everything but the 'n' items? Very useful explanation though, thanks!